# Is there a creature or spell that creates diseases broadly (beyond the normal means of a contagion spell)?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, disease

Are there ways to contract or create specific diseases (beyond just running into an infected creature or the contagion spell)? I’ve been looking for 3/3.5 creatures or spells that can create and bestow virtually any disease; especially diseases like those found in the book of vile darkness.

The source/ delivery method is not especially important.